# Use variable in eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
index = 5;
alert($('ul li:eq(index) a',context).html());
```

This script will alert : `"Null"`, but when I change to:

```
alert($('ul li:eq(5) a',context).html()); // it works
```

So what is wrong with this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the variable value, not the `index` string...

```
index = 5;
alert($('ul li:eq(' + index + ') a',context).html());
```

**A lot more readable and little faster version is:**

If `context` is a DOM node:

```
$(context).find('ul li').eq(index).find('a').html()
```

If `context` is a jQuery object:

```
context.find('ul li').eq(index).find('a').html()
```

Comment: @Snoob. No problem, I would use the second option.

Comment: Lol, it require accepting an anwser in 10 minutes, but your answer only in 30s

Comment: @JaredFarrish. Faster is in the guts of the machine... Actually the big improvement is not using the context overload of jQuery, if you look at the source code, you will see it calls `find`, so you can make it more readable and save the overhead.

Comment: I understand the approach and it's merits. Maybe I'm suffering form chaining "overload".

Answer (score 5):

```
alert($('ul li:eq('+index+') a',context).html());
```

Because when you use `'ul li:eq(index) a'` the resulting selector is the same which is `'ul li:eq(index) a'`.

But when you use string concatenation like `'ul li:eq(' + index + ') a'` the resulting selector becomes `'ul li:eq(5) a'` because JS interpreter replace the value of `index` variable and build the new string.